# Bash here docs <<- skipping leading blanks

Tags: bash

I can do this:

```
declare foo -r -d '' <<- 'EOF'
->-> Sopra la panca
->-> la capra campa
EOF
```

(where `->` represents a TAB)

The leading tabs will then be ignored.

Can `<<-` be used to skip/ignore leading `space`s, not just `tab`s?

Comment: No. only leading tab characters will be stripped. Read the `man` page

Comment: Prince John, I think that should be an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote
[from Greg](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument)

```
In this form, all leading tab characters (not spaces!) will be removed. There is 
no provision for removing leading spaces, or leading tabs-and-spaces. (Recall the
syntactic restrictions of Makefiles, and you'll be OK.)
```